# How to set Cookie in soapUI using a Groovy test step?

Tags: groovy, soapui

I need to send a http request with cookie header set that is taken from a file. I already know how to read the file and extract the cookie but don't know how to pass it to request.

I've written the following piece of code:

```
Random random = new Random();
String line = random.nextInt(3)+1;
def testCase = testRunner.testCase;
File f = new File("F:/data.txt");
cookies = f.readLines();
String cookie = cookies.getAt(line);
// I can read the headers
def headerWatch =  testRunner.testCase.testSteps['HTTP Test Request'].testRequest.response.getRequestHeaders()
log.info(headerWatch)
// TODO : set cookie to request
```

Answer (score 2):

To create a new cookie, you can use the following:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport
def myCookieStore = HttpClientSupport.getHttpClient().getCookieStore()

import org.apache.http.impl.cookie.BasicClientCookie
def myNewCookie = new BasicClientCookie("cookie_name", "cookie_value")
myNewCookie.version = 1
myNewCookie.domain = "qa.test"
myCookieStore.addCookie(myNewCookie)
```

Additional information on cookies is available here: http://siking.wordpress.com/2013/07/25/soapui-cookie-management/

Comment: After I add these codes , it throws an error: unable to resolve class org.apache.http.impl.Cookie.BasicClientCookie

Comment: What version of SoapUI?

Comment: I use soapUI 5.0.0, the lastest version

Comment: Something must be wrong with your installation. `org.apache.http.impl.Cookie.BasicClientCookie` is shipped with SoapUI.

Comment: I saw the jar in my lib, so it confuses me why it cannot work

Comment: As @AaronJacobson pointed out, `org.apache.http.impl.cookie` is package name, and should be all lower case. Corrected my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error with importing the BasicClientCookie class in soapui.  The import is case sensitive and the 'C' in Cookie should be lowercase.

```
import org.apache.http.impl.cookie.BasicClientCookie
```